# what kind of b should be if $\cos(bx)=\sin^2x+1$

Tags: analysis

If $$\cos(bx)=\sin^2x+1$$ has no solutions other than $x=0$,
then b should be: rational or irrational???

Tried: let $b=1$ then the equation holds whenever $x=2k\pi$. So b should be irrational...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, since $|\cos y| \le 1$ for all $y$, and $\sin^2 x \ge 0$, you must have $\sin^2 x = 0$ and $\cos(bx) = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the maximum of the left side and the minimum of the right side are ...

Comment: Nice, +1. ${}{}$